# Find sub class of a class and return list of elements

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I intend to scrape certain countries from a webpage that are under chapter 4 and return a list of those countries. The challenge is that I cannot retrieve the tag

## USING READ HTML

```
reqUS = Request('https://www.state.gov/reports/country-reports-on-terrorism-2019/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'})
US = urlopen(reqUS).read()

# print(US)

# Create  a soup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(US, 'html.parser')


# find class "floated-right well"
#Terrorist_list = soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "report__section-title"})

Chapter4 = (soup.find('h2', class_="report__section-title",id="report-toc__section-7"))
#print(Chapter4)

# Give location where text is stored which you wish to alter
unordered_list = soup.find("h2", {"id": "report-toc__section-7"})
print(unordered_list)
```

Comment: What countries do you want to get from that page?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `#report-toc__section-7` as an anchor, and `TERRORIST SAFE HAVENS` as a start point and `COUNTERING TERRORISM ON THE ECONOMIC FRONT` as an endpoint. Use those as the text to go into `:-soup-contains` to filter with css selectors to obtain only the `p` tags between those with a child `strong` tag (using `:has`). You need to also add in `:not` to remove the `p` with child `strong`s after, and including, the endpoint. From that filtering pull out the child `strong` tags which have the locality and countries.

Loop the returned list and test if `strong` text is all uppercase; if so, it is a locality and can be the key of a dictionary to which you add a list of following `strong` values as countries; repeating as you encounter each new locality. You can then pull out specific countries by locality.

For older bs4 versions replace `:-soup-contains` with `:contains`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get(
    'https://www.state.gov/reports/country-reports-on-terrorism-2019/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

items = soup.select('section:has(>#report-toc__section-7) p:has(strong:-soup-contains("TERRORIST SAFE HAVENS")) ~ p:has(strong):not(p:has(strong:-soup-contains("COUNTERING TERRORISM ON THE ECONOMIC FRONT")), p:has(strong:-soup-contains("COUNTERING TERRORISM ON THE ECONOMIC FRONT")) ~ p) > strong')

d = {}

for i in items:
    if i.text.isupper():
        key = i.text
        d[key] = []
    else:
        value = i.text.strip()
        if value:
            d[key].append(value)
print(d)
```

Prints

[image]

Read more about css selectors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Comment: Really helpful. The only problem is that I get  the following error using :contains "Psuedo-element found at position 49"

Comment: New code: '''
items = soup.select('section:has(>#report-toc__section-7) p:has(strong::contains("TERRORIST SAFE HAVENS")) ~ p:has(strong):not(p:has(strong:-soup-contains("COUNTERING TERRORISM ON THE ECONOMIC FRONT")), p:has(strong:-soup-contains("COUNTERING TERRORISM ON THE ECONOMIC FRONT")) ~ p) > strong')'''